# WPF Creating movable (allow drag and drop) UI controls in the run time

Tags: c#, wpf

i am working on state machine test design tool, but i am facing issue with dragging and drop the added nodes in the design panel. Since these nodes are added in the run-time. i can not implement the drag drop event for each added node , knowing that i am using WPF with caliburn.micro platform and MVVM

XAML code

```
        <!-- Column 2 : Design panel-->
        <StackPanel  x:Name="DesignPanelState" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"  Grid.RowSpan="2" >
        <ItemsControl x:Name="Nodes" MouseLeftButtonDown="Nodes_MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin ="3" Padding="3">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" MouseMove="Nodes_MouseMove">
                            <Button x:Name="NodeIdx" Content="{Binding NodeName}" MinWidth="50" MinHeight="50"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
```

[Image of UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyCPA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer of my question in https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15354/Dragging-Elements-in-a-Canvas

I integrated class DragCanvas.cs into my project and included following line in the header of the XAML file
xmlns:jas="clr-namespace:WPF.JoshSmith.Controls"

and XAML code became

```
        <!-- Column 2 : Design panel-->
        <jas:DragCanvas x:Name="DesignPanelState"
      Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" 
      AllowDragging="{Binding ElementName=Move, Path=IsChecked}"
      AllowDragOutOfView="False">
            <ItemsControl  x:Name="Nodes">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel >

                    <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                        <Canvas AllowDrop="True"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button x:Name="NodeIdx" BorderBrush="Aquamarine" BorderThickness="1" Content="{Binding NodeName}" MinWidth="50" MinHeight="50"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </jas:DragCanvas>
```